# Why does Request.Cookies return null in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies

I'm trying to use `Cookie` in my asp.net mvc project.
The Cookie is created and it has value. but I can't read it.
I created cookie with this code:

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("UserSettings", "value");
cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10);
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

And this code is for reading:

```
return HttpContext.Request.Cookies["UserSettings"].Value;
```

But in reading cookie I have this error:

> object reference not set to an instance of an object

I really confused why! I searched a lot and It has wasted my time.
Where did I make a mistake?

**Update**
I checked Application tab in developer tools chrome. The cookie exists.

Comment: At which stage of your processing the cookie reading attempt is made? I could imagine a scenario where Cookies are not available yet. You could verify if you attempt to read it directly within the MVC Action, using `Request.Cookies["UserSettings"]` (omit `HttpContext`)

Answer (score 2):

Are you reading the Request property in the constructor of your controller if yes It doesn't exist at that point in the controller life cycle.
you can override the Initialize method:

```
protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
{
//check request context for cookie.

}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Are you reading the `Request.Cookies` just after calling the `Response.Cookies.Add`? If yes, it's still null, because the `Request.Cookies` will be populated with the next request.
- What is the domain of the written cookie? Is it the same as the domain of the cookie reader? By default, cookies are shared by all pages that are in the same domain an are not visible to all other sub domains.
- `HttpContext.Request.Cookies["UserSettings"]` can return a null value. So you should check its value first.
- Also checkout the network tab of your browser's developer tools to see if the written cookie is present or not?

Comment: 1- read & write action are different. 2- domain is same. 4- edit my question

Comment: What's the size of the cookie? If it's more than 4K, it won't work.

Comment: I know, it is just 44 byte